# How do I retain a PDF form widget's design when setting its value using JavaScript in Acrobat?

Tags: javascript, widget, field, acrobat, adobe-indesign

I've created an interactive PDF form in InDesign and I need to perform some heavy JavaScript manipulation on it. The problem is that widget design is overriden when using JavaScript to set the field's value. Here's what a checkbox, for example, should look like when checked:

http://i45.tinypic.com/axl6u.png

However performing:

```
var f = this.getField("Checkbox");
f.value = "Yes";
```

in the JS Console results in the widget's appearance defaulting to acrobat's:

http://i49.tinypic.com/11qmm1g.png

I've tried every single widget property documented in Acrobat's Javascript API Reference to no avail. Initially, checking/unchecking using the mouse works fine. Once the value has been set using JS, Acrobat's default black check character is used for all subsequent toggling, including when using the mouse...

How does InDesign export interactive PDFs with custom icons for widgets? Is there any way to enforce the use of those icons using JS in Acrobat Pro? What's the difference between selecting a checkbox or a radio button using the mouse and setting its value using JS?